# How to manage remote IIS instances from Windows 10 Professional?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, iis, windows-10

I have a number of instances of IIS running on remote Windows Server 2019 boxes.  I want to be able to manage them from IIS on my local Windows 10 Professional box.

To that end, I went to the Windows Features dialog and checked pretty much everything under Internet Information Services.  However, when I fire up IIS, I don't see an option to `Add Server...`.

Am I missing something simple or is the option simply not available from Windows 10 Professional?

Answer (score 2):

Installing IIS itself only configures your machine to allow it to run websites etc locally, not remotely manage servers. To remotely manage a server you need to install the RSAT (Remote Server Administration Tools).

There's a complete guide to the process here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-server-administration-tools

but on Windows 10 you basically need to go into Settings > Apps > Optional Features > Add, and then install the relevant RSAT features, which in your case is probably just `RSAT: Server Manager`.

Then once Server Manager is installed you'll be able to use that to connect to and manage the remote server.

To quote directly from that guide, "The tools installed as part of Remote Server Administration Tools for Windows 10 cannot be used to manage the local client computer. Regardless of the tool you run, you must specify a remote server, or multiple remote servers, on which to run the tool. Because most tools are integrated with Server Manager, you add remote servers that you want to manage to the Server Manager server pool before managing the server by using the tools in the Tools menu."

Comment: I installed it, but when I fire up Server Manager, right click on the server and select IIS, it brings up IIS Manager pointing to local copy of IIS.  So something is definitely missing.  And when I bring up the `Computer Management`, IIS is not under the list of `Services and Applications`, where it normally sits.  Maybe I need to install something on the server itself?  https://i.imgur.com/LkUvl6Y.png